# respond_with ArgumentError (Nil location provided. Can't build URI.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller that responds_with JSON for all of the RESTful actions, index, create, update etc,

```
class QuestionsController

 respond_to :json

   def index
     respond_with Question.all
   end

end
```

However, I also have other actions in the controller. For example, in one method, it checks whether a response was correct and then tries to return a variable with a boolean true or false

```
respond_with correct_response  #either true or false
```

However, this is giving me the error

```
ArgumentError (Nil location provided. Can't build URI.):
```

There will also be other methods that I'll wish to respond with multiple values. In Sinatra, you can do this to respond with json

```
{:word => session[:word], :correct_guess => correct_guess, :incorrect_guesses => session[:incorrect_guesses], :win => win}.to_json
```

How would I do that in Rails?

So, two questions, what's the proper way to write this

```
respond_with correct_response
```

and how to respond_with multiple values in a way similar to the example I showed from a Sinatra app.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You want [`ActionController::Base#render`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render), not `respond_with`. The proper way to do what you're trying to achieve here is:

```
render json: {word: session[:word], correct_guess: correct_guess, incorrect_guesses: session[:incorrect_guesses], win: win}
```

Comment: ok, thanks, but if I want to render multiple values, in the same way that that hash is rendered in the example I provided, how do I do it then?

Comment: It's a shame using `respond_with` in POST calls results in this. I prefer it over `render`. But thanks anyway! :D

Comment: It has nothing to do with POST. `respond_with` is built for responding with ActiveRecord objects (ActiveModel really, but that's a different point). You are responding with a boolean, which is not meant to be handled by respond_with. POST has nothing to do with it- you can use respond_with on any type of HTTP action as long as the object you're responding with acts like ActiveRecord.

Comment: I also faced the same for the POST request. render solved my issue. Thank you @Chris Cashwell.

Answer (score 7):

`respond_with` is actually OK for this scenario--it just happens to do some magic for you and relies on having access to info it needs; take a look at Rails 4.1.9's [actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.9/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb).

In your case, `ArgumentError (Nil location provided. Can't build URI.)` is actually telling the truth--it's trying to determine a URL to use from the `location` header setting but isn't able to figure it out.  I'd wager you could get your code working if you gave it one:

```
class QuestionsController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with Question.all, location: questions_url
  end
end
```